# OpenCV - Scale Invariant Detection of Multiple Instances of the Same Object in One Image?

Tags: c++, opencv, object, scale, detection

I have one query image.  There can be 0-4 instances of this query image in the search image.  They can be at different scales, but never rotated.  I need to detect all instances of the query image, along with the bounding boxes that contain them.

One solution I've thought of is to use feature detection and use knnMatch() with k = 4 to find the 4 best matches for each feature.  Then use some type of cluster algorithm to group the matches together.  The problem with this is that the instances of the query image can be adjacent to eachother.  In that case, a cluster algorithm couldn't group the different matches for each instance.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this?  I have almost no experience with OpenCV, so I'm not sure what my options are.

Thanks in advance.